# C - runtime error while printing string(using a pointer)

Tags: c, string, pointers, runtime-error, dev-c++

I have a problem with a simple C program and i need your help.
I declare a string, using a pointer.Using scanf I give it a value from stdin.Later I try printing this string.It all compiles well,but when i run the program, it accepts my string,and when it gets to printing, i recieve a run-time error with return value 3221225477.

Where is the problem here?
 I'm using DEV C++ IDE btw.

Note: I also tried doing the same on ideone.com online compiler and it doesn't give a runtime error,but instead of string given in stdin, it prints (null).

 Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int     main(void)
{
    char *string;

    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("Hello,%s !", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1.) there are no "runtime errors" in C. 2.) `string` isn't initialized and doesn't point to any usable memory, writing there is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate space for the variable string.
For example:

```
char *string;
int i;
scanf("%d", &i);
string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*i);
```

And then you can read from input and print the string